# como fazer as funções do jquery 1.9.1 com o IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

tenho essa função que funciona no Chrome, firefox, IE11 porém precisava usar ele no IE8 mais não executa a função alguém conhece uma maneira de burlar isso?

```
$(function(){
    //GERAIS
    var errmsg = $('.msg');
    var forms  = $('form');
    var botao  = $('.j_buttom');
    var urlpost = 'php/crud.php';

    //errmsg.hide();
    botao.attr("type","submit");    

    forms.submit(function(){ 
        errmsg.fadeOut("fast"); 
        return false; 
    });

    function carregando(){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="load"><img src="img/load.gif" alt="Carregando..."> Aguarde, enviando requisição!</p>').fadeIn("fast");   
    }

    function errosend(){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="erro"><strong>Erro inesperado,</strong> Favor contate o admin!</p>').fadeIn("fast"); 
    }

    //GENÉRICAS
    function errodados( mensagem ){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="erro">'+mensagem+'</p>').fadeIn("fast");
    }

    function sucesso( mensagem ){
        errmsg.empty().html('<p class="accept">'+mensagem+'</p>').fadeIn("fast");
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        url: urlpost,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: carregando,
        error: errosend 
    });

    //CADASTRO
    var cadastro = $('form[name="cadastro"]');

    cadastro.submit(function(){
        var dados = $(this).serialize();
        var acao = "&acao=cadastro";
        var sender = dados+acao;

        $.ajax({
            data: sender,
            success: function( resposta ){
                alert(resposta);    
                if(resposta === "1"){
                    errodados('<strong>Erro ao cadastrar:</strong> Existem campos em branco!');
                }else if(resposta === "2"){
                    errosend();
                }else{
                    sucesso( 'Parabéns <strong>'+resposta+'</strong>, seu cadastro foi realizado!' );   
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
                //location.href="http://www.upinside.com.br";
                cadastro.find("input:text").val('');
            }   
        });

        //alert(sender);
    });
});
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece no console do IE8?

Comment: O jQuery 1.x.x é compativel com o IE8

Comment: não executa a função, porem nas versão IE11 funciona

Comment: o erro no console é object expected